# Push to segmented control segment by segment's title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that contains 3 segments. Once my application starts, the application automatically starts at segment 1. I would like my application to start at segment 3. I do not want to simply select the index of the segment array like so:

```
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
```

I would like my view to move to the segment that contains a certain title:

```
if (self.segmentControl.title isEqualToString:@"SomeTitle") {
     //Do something
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a way to do this. The closest you could get to it would be to `#define` the indexes in the class you're using them.

Something like this:

```
#define SomeTitle_Index 0 
#define SomeOtherTitle_Index 1
#define AnotherTitle_Index 2
```

Then selecting them would be like this:

```
[self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:SomeOtherTitle_Index];
```

And to check index:

```
if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == SomeOtherTitle_Index){
     //Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly call the segmented control **valueChanged** action method.

For example, you have a **valueChanged** action method as

```
(IBAction)segmentIndexChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
   if (sender.title isEqualToString:@"SomeTitle") {
     //Do something
   }
}
```

Then the method call will be

```
self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 2; 
[self segmentIndexChanged:self.segmentControl];
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** To Select default velue in interface builder just uncheck selected property of index.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index=-1;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if ([[segment titleForSegmentAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"SomeTitle"]) {
            index=i;
        }
    }
    segment.selectedSegmentIndex=index;
```